# Updating Table with data from a Query Operation Must Use an Updateable Query

Tags: sql

was wondering if anyone can help me out with this.  I have a table and a query both of which have the same [Resource ID], [Resource Name] fields.  I am trying to update the [CBL_1_Date], and the [CBL_1_kW] fields in the table with the [CBL_x_Date] and [CBL_x_kW] fields of the query.  The problem is that when I try to run the query I keep getting "**Operation Must Use an Updateable Query**" error.

```
UPDATE tCBLAggregation 
INNER JOIN qBestof4CBLs_avg 
ON (tCBLAggregation.[Event Date] = qBestof4CBLs_avg.[Event Start Date]) 
      AND 
      (tCBLAggregation.[Resource ID] = qBestof4CBLs_avg.[Resource ID]) 
SET tCBLAggregation.CBL_1_Date = [qBestof4CBLs_avg].[CBL_x_Date], tCBLAggregation.CBL_1_kW = [qBestof4CBLs_avg].[AvgOfCBL_x_kW];
```

Comment: What database server/version?

Comment: Looks like `SQL Server` or `MS Access`.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a sub query for `qBestof4CBLs_avg` then you're not trying to update a non-updatable table expression.

In ANSI SQL (e.g: PostgreSQL / SQL Server):

```
UPDATE "tCBLAggregation" 
   SET "CBL_1_Date" = v.d, 
       "CBL_1_kW"   = v.x
  FROM (
          SELECT "Event Start Date" as esd, 
                 "Resource ID"      as rid,
                 "CBL_x_Date"       as d, 
                 "AvgOfCBL_x_kW"    as x
          FROM   "qBestof4CBLs_avg"
       ) v 
 WHERE "Event Date"  = v.esd
   AND "Resource ID" = v.rid;
```

Should be very similar in any reasonably ANSI SQL compliant database.

On reflection, `UPDATE ... INNER JOIN` looks like it might be MySQL (which is... not so compliant).

See @Eric 's answer in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1293330/how-can-i-do-an-update-statement-with-join-in-sql) for translations to other databases.

**edit:** removed confusing `x` table alias in sub-query.